# Execution time of very short function

Tags: search, execution

I am required to display the execution time of some searching algorithms. However, when I use start/end_t = clock(), it always displays 0.00000 due to low precision (even with double-type)

Please tell me how to display those running times.

```
int LinearSearch (int M[], int target, int size)
{
int k = 0;
for (k=0; k<size; k++)
{
    if(M[k]==target)
    {
        return k;
    }
    //else return -1;
}
}

 int LinearSentinelSearch (int M[],int target, int size)
{
int k = 0; 
M[size]=target;
while (M[k] != target)
    k++;
return k;
}



int binSearch(int List[], int Target, int Size) 
{
int Mid;
int low = 0;
int high = Size -1;
int count=0;
int a;

while( low <= high) 
{
    Mid = (low + high) / 2;

    if(List[Mid] == Target) return Mid;

    else if( Target < List[Mid] )
        high = Mid - 1;
    else
        low = Mid + 1;  
} 
return -1;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate the *mean* execution time by simply executing the algorithm multiple times N and then divide the total time by N. Using your `binSearch` as an example:

```
int i;
clock_t start, end;

start = clock();
for (i = 0 ; i < 1000 ; i++) {
    binSearch(/* your actual parameters here */);
}
end = clock();

printf("Mean ticks to execute binSearch: %f\n", (end - start) / 1000.0);
```